# Broadcast Join in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark and have a question around Broadcast Joins. We use Spark 2.4.0 and use Spark Temporary Views for data transformations -

```
create temporary view product as
select /*+ BROADCAST(b) */
a.custid, b.prodid
from cust a
join prod b
on a.prodid = b.prodid
```

I know there is a parameter for `broadcast` joins `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` which has a value of `10` i.e. `10MB`. But, I also read somewhere that the **maximum** size of a broadcast table could be `8GB`. What is the significance of these two values ?

For broadcasting a table/view, does the size always have to be in `MB` or, is it also possible to broadcast (with a hint) a table/view of `5GB` (for example) ? In that case, do I have to manipulate the value of the parameter `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` by setting it to a higher value (`=5120` i.e. `5GB`) ? Or, will it allow me to broadcast the table/view since it is below the max limit (i.e. `8GB`) ?

If I want to broadcast a table (in GBs) is it recommended from a query performance perspective ?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you do not explicitly state a broadcast via hint in the SQL of via DF syntax, then for tables of which stats are known up to size 10MB, Catalyst may elect to utilize a broadcast join approach.
- If you do explicitly state a broadcast join, then if the table size exceeds 8GB, Catalyst will ignore and use another join strategy over the broadcast join.
- More formally:

> If a broadcast hint is specified, the join side with the hint will be
> broadcasted irrespective of autoBroadcastJoinThreshold. If both sides
> of the join have the broadcast hints, the side with a smaller
> estimated physical size will be broadcasted. If there is no hint and
> if the estimated physical size of the table <
> autoBroadcastJoinThreshold then that table is broadcasted to all the
> executor nodes.

Should I broadcast" yes, if it means the query is faster and there are enough resources (to share).

Comment: thanks for your reply.. is it ok to broadcast a table/view of size in GB (< 8gb of course) for making a query join faster ?

Comment: if you have the resources and it goes faster, then go for it